# How to get Stanford CoreNLP Semgrex to find relation with NMOD?

Tags: stanford-nlp

In Stanford CoreNLP Semgrex I'm able to find all other relationships but the nmod rel. Any other relationship like:

```
 {}=A <nsubj {}=B
```

Works fine. But if I try to match a nmod relationship, it does not recognize the relationship:

```
{}=A >nmod {}=B
```

And it throws an error when matching nmod:in relationship:

```
{}=A >nmod:in {}=B
```

How do I find an nmod:in relationship in CoreNLP Semgrex?

Answer (score 0):

add backslashes around `nmod:in` may solve your problem

```
{}=A >/nmod:in/ {}=B
```